# Struts2 Form Tag

Tags: java, forms, struts2, tags

I am currently creating a web-application that is using Struts2 tags for form submission. One of the problem I see is that when I view page source it clearly shows my code, specifically how struts2 created the form. Something like this.

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="register_userBean_username" class="label">User Name:</label></td>
    <td
><input type="text" name="userBean.username" value="" id="register_userBean_username" class="class java.util.HashMap"/></td>
</tr>

      <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="register_userBean_password" class="label">Password:</label></td>
    <td
><input type="text" name="userBean.password" value="" id="register_userBean_password" class="class java.util.HashMap"/></td>
</tr>
```

Is there anyway to prevent the users to see the underlying code that struts2 created for my form?

Comment: Because I feel that it is a security issue? I want it to be minified

Comment: This is silly. The browser gets HTML, and it must be HTML. What do you hope to gain? You could create transfer objects that obfuscate underlying business logic/semantics, but then you have to write code you can't read. Not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a way to hide that without breaking the site. These informations seem to be vital to make the site work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Theolodis.
There is no way you can hide the html-code that struts tag created for you. The objective of struts tag is to minimize your view page coding by providing tags that expand to required html code. And how in the world would you prevent the user to view code which is on his browser.